# Problems accesing database in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had an app with PushBots and it was working fine. The client asked to migrate to FCM, so i did. And its mostly working perfectly. Im receiving notifications and, when the app is in the foreground, the notifications get saved. With the app in the background the notifications are still arriving without any trouble but in this case its not saving into database.

So i started with this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Timber.d("RECIEVED");

    RemoteMessage.Notification n = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    if (n != null) {

        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.setTitle(n.getTitle());
        notification.setMessage(n.getBody());
        notification.setDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

        NotificationDAO dao = new NotificationDAO(MyApp.getInstance());
        dao.create(notification);

        showNotification(n.getTitle(), n.getBody());
    }
}
```

So i thought the problem could be on the context, so i tried replacing `MyApp.getInstance()` with `getApplicationContext()`. That wasnt working, so then i changed `getApplicationContext()` with `this`. As it wasnt working neither i tried to do this access inside another thread, but none its working.

What am i doing wrong? The dao's method `create` is working in the rest of the application.

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use "context" in your FirebaseMesaagingService, you can use '**this**'

The hierarchy of classes is as below

FirebaseMessagingService extends Service which (Service) extends ContextWrapper
which inturn (ContextWrapper) extends Context

Hence you can directly use,

'MyFirebaseMessagingService.this' or simply 'this'

Comment: which context is it required `application`, `activity` ?

Comment: yes, i also tried with `this` context and isnt working

Comment: please post the exact error stack trace that you are getting ?